# Object became nil after view will appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, properties, uiviewcontroller

Following situation:

I got 2 views. On the firstview I m display Event data, on the seconde i can edit these data. If I switch to my seconde view and edit a value and return back to my firstview everything works as it should. But if I dont change this data and return back, my Event objecct is nil.

The funny part is: before I switch to my second view the user can decide(UIActionSheet) wich changes will he do (Name etc.). At this point i m logging that object and its nil. But on my viewWillAppear - its the seconde time the view loads - the object is NOT nil.

I changed the property attribute of my event object to (**strong**, nonatomic), so when i dont change something the object still exists..

I will provide some code as soon as i m at home, but maybe you have already a idea..

**Firstview**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


    [ADVThemeManager customizeView:self.view];

    [self initViewData];
    [self editViewStyles];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    NSLog(@"VIEW WILL APPEAR!!");
    NSLog(@"Eventname: %@", eventObject.name);
    NSLog(@"USERID: %@", appUser.userID);
// Logs proves that at second load of view the object is NOT nil!!! But Check ->     - (void)eventOptionSheet!!
    [self initViewData];
}

- (void) initViewData{
    self.invitedUserList.delegate = self;
    self.invitedUserList.dataSource = self;

    self.acceptedUserList.delegate = self;
    self.acceptedUserList.dataSource = self;

    dccon = [[DCConnector alloc]init];


    NSLog(@"Eventname: %@", eventObject.name);
    NSLog(@"USERID: %@", appUser.userID);

    invitedUsers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[eventObject.invitedUsers allObjects]];
    acceptedUsers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[eventObject.acceptedUsers allObjects]];

    eventDescriptionField.text = eventObject.descrptn;

    NSString *eventImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", eventObject.name, eventObject.date];

    if ([UtilitieHandler checkIfFileExistsWitchExstensio:eventImageName :@"png"]) {
        [eventImage setBackgroundImage:[UtilitieHandler loadImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", eventImageName]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    // Replace titleView
    CGRect headerTitleSubtitleFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44);
    UIView* _headerTitleSubtitleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:headerTitleSubtitleFrame];
    _headerTitleSubtitleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _headerTitleSubtitleView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    CGRect titleFrame = CGRectMake(0, 2, 200, 24);
    UILabel *titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:titleFrame];
    titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.98f green:0.96f blue:0.94f alpha:1.00f];
    titleView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Semibold" size:16];
    titleView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    titleView.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    titleView.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
    titleView.text = eventObject.name;
    titleView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    [_headerTitleSubtitleView addSubview:titleView];

    CGRect subtitleFrame = CGRectMake(0, 24, 200, 44-24);
    UILabel *subtitleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:subtitleFrame];
    subtitleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    subtitleView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.98f green:0.96f blue:0.94f alpha:1.00f];
    subtitleView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-SemiboldItalic" size:12];
    subtitleView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    subtitleView.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    subtitleView.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
    subtitleView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@", eventObject.createdBy.displayName];
    subtitleView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    [_headerTitleSubtitleView addSubview:subtitleView];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = _headerTitleSubtitleView;


    self.imageBackground.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Content_Box_Small.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];


    self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity =0.0f;
    self.invitedUserList.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.acceptedUserList.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];



    // init location to map
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.latitude = [eventObject.locLatitude doubleValue];
    coord.longitude = [eventObject.locLongitude doubleValue];

    MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  0.005, .longitudeDelta =  0.005};
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};

    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotation.coordinate = coord;

    [eventLocation setRegion:region];
    [eventLocation selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];

    //add gesture to map
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                               initWithTarget:self
                                               action:@selector(navigateMe)];
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0;
    [eventLocation addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

    //add right navbar item that handles invites, setting and more...
    UIBarButtonItem *settingsItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(eventOptionSheet)];
    settingsItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-btn-settings"];
    [settingsItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Semibold" size:12], UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:settingsItem];

}

- (void)eventOptionSheet{
    NSLog(@"CREATOR USER ID: %@", eventObject.createdBy.userID);
    NSLog(@"APP USER ID: %@", appUser.userID);

//On my second view load I probably want change more so i touch my navbar item and it leads me to this method. But here the logs are null(nil). If Change something on my seconde view this works fine again!!

    if ([eventObject.createdBy.userID isEqualToString:appUser.userID]) {
        eventCreatorSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:eventObject.name delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete Event"
                                               otherButtonTitles: @"Change location", @"Edit description", @"Invite more Contacts", nil];
        eventCreatorSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic;
        [eventCreatorSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
    }else{
        NSSet *invitedSet = eventObject.invitedUsers;
        NSSet *acceptedSet = eventObject.acceptedUsers;

        BOOL existsInInvitedList = [[invitedSet valueForKeyPath:@"objectID"] containsObject:appUser.objectID];
        BOOL existsInAcceptedList = [[acceptedSet valueForKeyPath:@"objectID"] containsObject:appUser.objectID];


        if (existsInInvitedList) {
            eventUserInvitedSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:eventObject.name delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Join", @"Decline", @"Chat creator", nil];
            eventUserInvitedSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic;
            [eventUserInvitedSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
        }else if (existsInAcceptedList){
            eventUserAcceptedSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:eventObject.name delegate:self
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Revoke invite", @"Chat creator", nil];
            eventUserAcceptedSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic;
            [eventUserAcceptedSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
        }
    }

}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    LastEventsViewController  *lastEvents;
    LocateEventViewController *locateEvent;
    EventMembersViewController *inviteMoreMembers;
    EventDescriptionViewController *eventDescriptionView;
    EventDTO *updateEventDTO;

    if (actionSheet == eventCreatorSheet) {
        // creator sheet
        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 0:
                //Remove Event clicked
                [dccon deleteEvent:eventObject];
                lastEvents = [[LastEventsViewController alloc]init];
                [[self navigationController]popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                break;
            case 1:
                //Edit location
                locateEvent = [[LocateEventViewController alloc]init];
                updateEventDTO = [[EventDTO alloc]init];
                [updateEventDTO setDTOWithEntity:eventObject];
                locateEvent.eventDTO = updateEventDTO;
                locateEvent.editEnabled = 1;
                [[self navigationController]pushViewController:locateEvent animated:YES];
                break;
            case 2:
                //Edit description
                eventDescriptionView = [[EventDescriptionViewController alloc]init];
                updateEventDTO = [[EventDTO alloc]init];
                [updateEventDTO setDTOWithEntity:eventObject];
                eventDescriptionView.eventDTO = updateEventDTO;
                eventDescriptionView.editEnabled = 1;
                [[self navigationController]pushViewController:eventDescriptionView animated:YES];
                break;
            case 3:
                //Invite more Contacts, check if numberOfInvites is < 50
                break;

        }
    }

    if (actionSheet == eventUserInvitedSheet) {
        //member sheet
        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 0:
                //join Event clicked
                NSLog(@"Event test: %@, appUserTest: %@", eventObject.name, appUser.userID);

                [dccon addAcceptedUserToEvent:eventObject :appUser];
                invitedUsers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[eventObject.invitedUsers allObjects]];
                acceptedUsers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[eventObject.acceptedUsers allObjects]];
                [acceptedUserList reloadData];
                [invitedUserList reloadData];
                break;
            case 1:
                //Decline Event
                [dccon removeInvitedUserFromEvent:eventObject :appUser];
                [dccon deleteEvent:eventObject];
                lastEvents = [[LastEventsViewController alloc]init];
                [[self navigationController]pushViewController:lastEvents animated:YES];
                break;
            case 2:
                //chat creator
                break;
        }
    }

    if (actionSheet == eventUserAcceptedSheet) {
        //member sheet
        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 0:
                //leave Event clicked
                [dccon removeAcceptedUserFromEvent:eventObject :appUser];
                [dccon deleteEvent:eventObject];
                lastEvents = [[LastEventsViewController alloc]init];
                [[self navigationController]pushViewController:lastEvents animated:YES];
                break;
            case 1:
                //chat creator
                break;
        }
    }

    if (actionSheet == changeImageSheet) {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;

        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 0:
                //Remove user clicked
                imagePickerController.delegate = self;
                imagePickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

                [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
                break;
            case 1:
                //Show Creator
                imagePickerController.delegate = self;
                imagePickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

                [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Seconde View**

```
@interface EventDescriptionViewController (){
    DCConnector *dccon;
}

@end

@implementation EventDescriptionViewController

@synthesize imageBackground, descriptionTextField, editEnabled, eventDTO;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [ADVThemeManager customizeView:self.view];

    [self initViewData];

    [self styleViews];
}

- (void) initViewData{
    UILabel *labelTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    labelTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    labelTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.98f green:0.96f blue:0.94f alpha:1.00f];
    labelTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Semibold" size:16];
    labelTitle.text = @"Event description";
    [labelTitle sizeToFit];
    UIView *viewTitle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:labelTitle.bounds];
    CGRect frameLbl = labelTitle.bounds;
    viewTitle.frame = frameLbl;
    [viewTitle addSubview:labelTitle];
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:viewTitle];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-tbl"]];
    self.imageBackground.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Content_Box_Small.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];


    if (editEnabled == 1) {
        UIBarButtonItem *newEventToggleView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(updateEvent)];
        [newEventToggleView setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Semibold" size:12.0], UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:newEventToggleView];

        descriptionTextField.text = eventDTO.description;

    }else{
        UIBarButtonItem *newEventToggleView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(initNextEventView)];
        [newEventToggleView setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Semibold" size:12.0], UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:newEventToggleView];

    }


    descriptionTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Semibold" size:14];

}

- (void)styleViews{
    [self.descriptionTextField.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
    [self.descriptionTextField.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:(107/255.0) green:(96/255.0) blue:(84/255.0) alpha:1.00f] CGColor]];

    self.descriptionTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    self.descriptionTextField.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
- (void)updateEvent{
    eventDTO.description = self.descriptionTextField.text;
    //Edit Event and push it to all members
    dccon = [[DCConnector alloc]init];
    [dccon updateEvent:eventDTO];
    EventOverviewController *overview = (EventOverviewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    overview.eventObject = (Event*)[dccon getObjectWithID:eventDTO.entitysID];
    overview.appUser = [dccon getAppUser];
    [[self navigationController]popToViewController:overview animated:YES];

}
```

**Firstview .h File**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Event *eventObject;
@property (strong, nonatomic) User *appUser;
//Other properties
```

**Second .h File**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) EventDTO *eventDTO;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger editEnabled;
```

Comment: which is the object type? NSString or another?

Comment: On the firstview its a NSManagedObject and in the second its a Custom NSObject.

Comment: You are talking about UIView or UIViewController-be specific. And please show your code so we can understand your problem. Your question is not enough descriptive to understand your problem

Comment: sry that i m late.. ill update my qeustion now!

Comment: I m talkin about UIViewController!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you are returning from your second view, you are setting an object with edited value and saving it. If the value is not edited, then that object will be nil and you are saving this nil object when returning to first view. If that is the case then add a condition checking for nil in second view case and save data only if it is not nil or is edited.

Comment: but why is it not nil in my viewWillAppear method?